# Vercel Deployment and Firebase Authentication - Unable to Customise Redirect URL Google Auth Provider Popup

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting, vercel

I had a question in regarding to the NextJS app which uses cloud firestore and firebase authentication which is deployed using the vercel deployment and domain is also registered using vercel itself.

- Deployment : Vercel
- Domain : Vercel
- Authentication : Firebase Authentication
- Database: Cloud Firestore
- Storage: Firebase Storage

I followed this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-4 but without firebase hosting and custom domain registration with firebase, I cannnot “Customizing the redirect domain for Google sign-inOn project creation”

Below configuration is not working

```
firebase config {
 authDomain: “customdomain.com”
}
```

I cannot change the domain to firebase hosting, because then I won”t be able to deploy using vercel.

Is there a way retain my vercel deployment and customise the redirect url while authenticating user.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase console> authentication > [firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06h70.png)
click the settings tab  
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9ZRt.png)

 then select Authorised domains and add your ustom domain, if you're unsure check the console firebase will usually tell you what domain is supposed to be added there for example mine looked like this

```
project-banner-eta.vercel.app
```

Answer (score 0):

this way work for me also

Firebase console> authentication > firebase console click the settings tab
settings
then select add  domains
this will pop out a domain box telling you to enter the domain name
copy your domain name and paste it there and click add
that it all. everything should be ok now